# iOS UIAutomation: switching apps

Tags: ios-ui-automation

I'm trying to use UI Automation to test writing and reading from `UIPasteboard` when switching apps. However, the script hangs after switching to the second app. I'm trying to make the test sleep to prevent it from hanging. I've tried using `waitForInvalid`, and `pushTimeout/popTimeout` and both methods don't seem to work and test still hangs before getting to `logElementTree` in the second app.

Here's my UI Automation script using `waitForInvalid`. (The "Pasteboard Sharing" button is where it launches the second app):

```
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();

target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().segmentedControls()[0].buttons()["1MB"].tap();
target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().buttons()["Pasteboard Sharing"].tap();

UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().mainWindow().buttons()["Paste & Go"]
    .tap();
UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().mainWindow().buttons()["Paste & Go"]
    .waitForInvalid();

target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().logElementTree();
```

And here's the script using `pushTimeout/popTimeout`:

```
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();

target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().segmentedControls()[0].buttons()["1MB"].tap();
target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().buttons()["Pasteboard Sharing"].tap();

UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().mainWindow().buttons()["Paste & Go"]
    .tap();

UIATarget.localTarget().pushTimeout(10);
UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().mainWindow().buttons()["Check Pasteboard"]
    .withValueForKey(1, "isVisible");
UIATarget.localTarget().popTimeout();

target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().logElementTree();
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to use the same script to test two apps. However, that is not possible if you only use UIA. With UIAutomation, you can only have one app as your target. Thus, switching to another app will just "hang" because the app being targeted is in the background. I've read somewhere that you can use Appium https://github.com/appium/appium to interact between two apps but I haven't use it myself.

Comment: Appium also uses UIAutomation in the background. So the limitations remains the same. Although this works well for Android(with or without appium)